# Can't find java class: NoClassDefFoundError: KTEngine (Kinetic Typography tool)

Tags: java, ubuntu, installation, typography

I am a Linux Ubuntu user.
I tried downloading and installing this interesting Kinetic Typography tool:

http://johnnylee.net/kt/dist/files/

It's quite old (2002) and poorly documented.

When I try to compile and run, I get the error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: KTEngine/java
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to run it with:

```
java KTEngine.java
```

That's not how you run a Java program. You say you've compiled it, but you haven't said *how* you've done so...

Note that having downloaded the code, `KTEngine` doesn't have a `main` method either, so that's not going to work anyway.

It looks like it's just a library, so you'd need to use it within your own application, rather than it being an application in itself.

Comment: mm... it looks trickier than I thought then. I tried compiling it with the "javac" command. Thanks.